# iPad sticks when scrolling to notification screen

Tags: ipad, performance

iPad 4th gen (MD520LL/A) with iOS 10.3.3

As the title says, the screen sticks when scrolling to the notifications page. I've removed all notification panels on the screen so all that is left is the edit button and the wallpaper, but it still stick for about 7-10 seconds anytime you access that page. Scrolling through the app pages is quick and snappy.

Soft and hard reboots have not changed this behavior.

Comment: Time to try backing up and reinstalling your operating system. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201252

Comment: I figured. I did try a full reset of all settings while keeping data and that was no help at all. I will try to update if the full erase works or not. Wasn't my device and gave it back for them to restore.